# How to get current pid of current process in dart?

Tags: dart

I need to get the pid of current processs on flutter,
but I cann't find any static method in Process.dart, how to get it?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/pid.html ?

Comment: @jamesdlin it's ok, thanks you!

Comment: Hi @cheasonxie, would you mind going ahead and accepting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68183412/758334) if it was helpful? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Import `dart:io` and use the `pid` property.

```dart
import 'dart:io';
...
print('pid: $pid');
```

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-io/Process/pid.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/pid.html

Comment: This does not work on web ? I got errors

Comment: @TSR I haven't tried myself, but I wouldn't expect it to work as a Flutter Web app that runs in a browser sandbox environment. Getting the pid only makes sense when you're running it as a dedicated process on a machine you control so you can send identify it and potentially send signals to it (like SIGTERM or SIGKILL).